# Primavera P6 Professional R8.3.2 compatibility with SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2016

Tags: weblogic, primavera

We are currently using Primavera P6 Professional R8.3.2 with SQL Server 2008 R2. We are going to upgrade the SQL Server version from 2008 R2 to either 2014 or 2016 version. Could you please confirm that there are any compatibility issues between Primavera R8.3.2 and SQL Server 2014 or SQL Server 2016?

**Edit:**

We are going to migrate upgrade Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2016. SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2016 are only supported in Windows Server 2016. Primavera web application is currently running in Apache/Weblogic OEL5.7 Server. We are going to upgrade Apache/Weblogic OEL5.7 Server to Linux 6.10 and 7.5(OEL) Server.

I have checked the tested configurations Excel file for compatibility issues. I am able to find the specified new Windows Server details and SQL Server details in the newer version (17. 7) of Primavera Excel file. But I am not able to find the Primavera web application's compatibility with new Linux 6.10 and 7.5(OEL) Server in the tested configurations Excel file. Could you please confirm the Primavera web application's compatibility with new Linux 6.10 and 7.5(OEL) Server?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to search Oracle's P6 tested configuration document. For every release of P6, they produce an xls spreadsheet that lists what infrastructure they have tested the tool on.

Here's a link to Oracle's documentation library: https://docs.oracle.com/en/industries/construction-engineering/primavera-p6-eppm/index.html where you can get the xls file.

PS: Now the xls file has been renamed "client system requirements" - search that or "tested configurations".

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure I can help you. The tested configurations doc indicate what infrastructure is supported. I would contact Oracle Support directly to get confirmation.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please check and provide your inputs.